# C++ Search TXT File return int

Tags: c++, function, int, text-files

The code bellow is from a larger one I'm working on. It searches for a username in a txt file. If the name is found, it returns ether a int 0 or int 1. It compiles and runs but no matter if the user is in the txt file or not, it always runs the shut down action making me think the function returns 0 every time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int DoThis(int UF);

int main(void)
{
    int z;
    z = DoThis(0);

    if(z == 1){RunThing;}
    else if(z == 0){ShutDown;}

return 0;
}

int DoThis(int UF)
{
int offset;
std::cin >> NameToCheck;
Myfile.open("FilePath")

if(Myfile.is_open())
    {
        while(!Myfile.eof())
        {
            getline(Myfile,line);
            if((offset = line.find(NameToCheck, 0)) != std::string::npos) 
            {
                while(Myfile >> FirstName >> LastName)
                {
                    return = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    Myfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File not found.";
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RockOnRockOut: UF is an int variable. And the capital's are just how I write it. Helps me navigate my code.

Comment: You're using `==` where you mean `=` in your assignments to `UserFound`.

Comment: @ooga Looks like he copy-pasted from a larger chunk of code, since there are a ton of mistakes there.

Comment: @luk27R It's bad practice to capitalize variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell exactly without seeing the actual code, but it looks like it's always returning 0 because you're overwriting what's in the variable `UserFound` for each line. When you find the name, return 1 - this way you won't have to go through the rest of the file and possibily cause other errors.

Have the last statement of the function be `return 0;` in case you haven't found it or the file could not be opened.

For reading the file line-by-line, you don't need the second `while` loop. All you need is to check whether the `line` string contains the `NameToCheck` string. If found, return 1. If you reach the end of the file, return 0.

Comment: Fixed the example code to become the changes I made so far. The output still is 0. Am I searching through the txt file wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing `while(Myfile >> FirstName >> LastName)`? If it was found in that line, just return 1. Where did you declare `FirstName` and `LastName`?

Comment: In another part of the code while(Myfile << FirstName << LastName) is used to accept users and puts their name in that order in the txt file, then makes room under it if another user inputs their name. while(Myfile >> FirstName >> LastName) checks each line to see if the user previously added theirs in the list from earlier.

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't do that. You are already checking each line by using `getline` and `string::find()`

Comment: So you are already reading the file line-by-line, right? You do `getline(Myfile,line);`, which means `line` now is a string which stores one line from your file. Now you need to see if the `line` string contains the `NameToCheck` string. if the condition `(line.find(NameToCheck) != std::string::npos)` is `true`, then `line` contains the name so you can just return 1 because you found it. If you have gone through each line and you reach the end of the file then return 0, meaning that you haven't found the name.

Comment: Got it working! Thank you! All I did was remove while(Myfile >> FirstName >> LastName). Took a while for it to click that I just need to remove it. Once I did, along with the other hints given, everything is working smoothly! I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Okay, I will modify my answer to include what I explained in the comments.